# Convert a string to anonymous parameter to be send to object routeValues from ActionLink method (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a general method which generates a link structure based on current controller, current action and current optional parametr (if any).

```
public static string GetLink(this HtmlHelper helper, RouteData routeData) {
   ...
   foreach(var item in routeData.Values){
      if(!item.key.Equals("controller") && !item.key.Equals("action")) {
         url = helper.ActionLink("text link", "myAction", "myController", 
            new { /* here I want to convert item.Key to anonymous param */ = "2" } );
      }
   } 
}
```

I put there a comment `/* here I want to convert item.Key to anonymous param */`

How to achieve this ?

Thanks

**I solved issue. Please use `UrlHelper` instead of `HtmlHelper` and generate a `RouteValueDictionary` object to put anonymous optional parameters**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested this but try creating a `RouteValueDictionary` from your item and key.

```
public static string GetLink(this HtmlHelper helper, RouteData routeData)
{
    foreach(var item in routeData.Values)
    {
        if(!item.Key.Equals("controller") && !item.Key.Equals("action"))
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(item);
            var url = helper.ActionLink("text link", "myAction", "myController", routeValues, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: url returns `http://localhost:64840/?Count=0&Keys=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BKeyCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D&Values=System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602%2BValueCollection%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.Object%5D`

Comment: It all depends on what type item.Key and item.Value are?

Comment: `item.Key` is string and `item.Value` is an object

Comment: Check the method parameters of helper.ActionLink. You need to add a null at the end (updated answer). It was calling the wrong method overload previously.

Comment: By the way, I solved issue by using `UrlHelper` instead of `HtmlHelper` ! Thank you very much for `RouteValueDictionary` point. Accept answer and upvote !

Comment: It would also be useful to update your question with your UrlHelper solution for future reference.